# Continue to resize div after click event

Tags: jquery, html, resize, window

I found bits of script that do what I want to do. This script moves my box up and down and on click event and resizes my div to a percentage of window height. Unfortunately, if someone resizes the brower window the div doesn't continue to resize. I have tried taking out the height window function from the click event, and put it below it and/or found other resize scripts on this site, but nothing happens. It only resizes on this click event. Can you help?

My div tag is anchored at the bottom of the browser window and slides up.

```
jQuery(function( $ ){

   var container = $( "#content" );

   $( "a" ).click(

        function( event ){

           $('#content').height(function(){
           return $(window).height() * 0.47;
           });

           event.preventDefault();

           if (container.is( ":visible" )){

              container.slideUp( 500 );

           } else {

              container.slideDown( 500 );

              }
           }
      );
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is adding a resize listener, and factoring out your actual logic like so:

```
jQuery(function( $ ){
    var resizeFunction = function(event){
       $('#content').height(function(){
            return $(window).height() * 0.47;
       });

       if (event != null){
           event.preventDefault();
       }
       if (container.is( ":visible" )){

          container.slideUp( 500 );

       } else {

          container.slideDown( 500 );

          }
       }
    var container = $( "#content" );

    $( "a" ).click(resizeFunction(event))
    $(window).resize(resizeFunction(null))
});
```

Comment: I think there is a syntax error here at var container = $( "#content" );

Comment: thanks. When I put this in my page and click my link, nothing happens now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen for the window resize event and resize the content container.

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    if (container.is(':visible')) {
        container.height(function() {
          return $(window).height() * 0.47;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: and this would go where? is this extra to what I already have or does it replace something. I added it to the end of my script as a single unit, but nothing happened.

Comment: Ok, I figured this out, and it works beautifully. Thanks. And for any other newby to this. I put it just above the last }); closing brackets.

Comment: @Visualtribe Glad you figured it out. If this helped you, please mark the answer as correct.